# How many Unique numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

$\require{cancel}$
I saw a meme that fraction $$\frac{163}{326}=\frac{1\cancel6\cancel3}{\cancel{3}\cancel{6}2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
And It means that
$$1\leq a_i,b_i \leq 9, a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{N},\\\sum_{i=1}^n 10^{i-1}a_i=\overline{a_n...a_2a_1}\\\frac{\overline{a_n...a_2a_1}} {\overline{b_n...b_2b_1}}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{a_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^n{b_i}}$$

So,I have question that how many this kind of things. han I found some examples $$\frac{49}{98},\frac{19}{95},\frac{16}{64}, \frac{26}{65},\frac{14}{63},\frac{18}{45}, \frac{15}{24},\frac{22}{165},\frac{44}{198},\frac{62513}{312565}$$ They have something special? And it is infinite that$ (\{a_n,...,a_2,a_1\},\{b_n,...b_2,b_1\})$??

---

I got the answer.

> If$$\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a_2}{b_2}=...=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$
>   Than$$ \frac{\overline{a_n...a_2a_1}} {\overline{b_n...b_2b_1}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n{b_i}}$$

And this can solve when $a_n,b_n>9$ for example the case $$\frac{540540540}{864864864}=\frac{5+40+5+40+5+40}{8+64+8+64+8+64}=\frac{5}{8}$$or$$\frac{5707070}{9131312}=\frac{5+70+70+70}{8+112+112+112}=\frac{5}{8}$$ Therefore we could crate like $$\frac{21818...18}{98181...81}=\frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: I don't think you wrote a definition for these numbers correctly. For example, $$\frac{14}{63}=\frac{1\times4}{6\times3}=\frac29$$ but there are no digits which cancel during this process.

Comment: Unless you pose some restrictions it is trivial to find an arbitrary large number. Since you can divide 11111111111 (or however many 1's you want) by itself to obtain 1 and since it contains no zeroes ,the product, of the entries of the numerator and denominator(respectivly) will be the same and also equal 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably digits of $0$ are not allowed, and we don't include trivialities
such as $xx/xx = x/x$.  The fractions  $<1$
with numerators and denominators of up to $3$ digits that work (cancelling all but one digit of numerator and denominator) are 
$$\eqalign{\frac{16}{64},& \frac{19}{95}, \frac{26}{65}, \frac{49}{98}, \frac{124}{217}, \frac{127}{762}, \frac{138}{184}, \frac{139}{973}, \frac{145}{435}, \frac{148}{185},\cr 
\frac{163}{326}, &\frac{166}{664}, \frac{182}{819}, \frac{187}{748}, \frac{199}{995}, \frac{218}{981}, \frac{244}{427}, \frac{266}{665}, \frac{273}{728}, \frac{316}{632},\cr
\frac{327}{872}, &\frac{364}{637}, \frac{412}{721}, \frac{424}{742}, \frac{436}{763}, \frac{448}{784}, \frac{455}{546}, \frac{484}{847}, \frac{499}{998}, \frac{545}{654}}
$$

Infinite families include
$$\frac{16\ldots 6}{6\ldots 64} = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$ \frac{19\ldots 9}{9\ldots 95} = \frac{1}{5}$$
$$ \frac{26\ldots 6}{6 \ldots 65} = \frac{2}{5}$$ and
 $$ \frac{49\ldots9}{9\ldots98} = \frac{4}{8}$$

Comment: Thanks alot!! There are more general solution about this? Or should I calculated